# MVC Music Store error - unable to log in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is the error I am getting

Unable to open the physical file "C:\TFSPersonal\Jareds Music Store\MVCMusicStore\App_Data\aspnetdb_log.ldf". Operating system error 5: "5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)".
Cannot create file 'C:\TFSPersonal\Jareds Music Store\MVCMusicStore\App_Data\aspnetdb_log.LDF' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'ATLASCS\jared'.
File activation failure. The physical file name "C:\TFSPersonal\Jareds Music Store\MVCMusicStore\App_Data\aspnetdb_log.ldf" may be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stop the mssql server, delete the .ldf file not .mdf and please be sure that folder has read/write permisson for iis user. if it's not work please comment maybe i'm wrong

Comment: I changed the permissions from read-only which I forgot to do when I copied it to a new location, it works now and I didn't delete the .ldf file

Comment: when i got an database error i'm always looking for permissions cuz i'm forgetting it always ;) i'm happy to solve